# Assigning priority to security access levels

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following access levels for my app

```
type accessLevels = "ReadOnly" | "Write" | "Admin";
```

The backend returns an array of `level` object that contains the access level.

```
const levels = [
    {
        access: "ReadOnly"
    },
    {
        access: "Write"
    }
]
```

Based on the above, I show/hide certain parts of the app through:

```
const hasWriteAccess: boolean = level.some((level) => {
    return level.access === "Write" || level.access === "Admin";
});
```

I'm trying to get around doing `level.access === "Write" || level.access === "Admin"` and instead do something like `level.access > "ReadOnly`. This imo would simplify the logic. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: have you thought to apply a numerical value to your types?   a>b>c kinda thing?

Comment: You'd simplify the logic but your type definition would become less understandable if you just used integers instead of plain English.

Comment: @Fallenreaper what Daniel said.